# How do I get bibisco running?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install `bibisco` on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit?

I couldn't find `bibisco` in Ubuntu Software Centre so I downloaded `bibisco-linux32-v1.5.0.tar.gz` from the developer's website ([www.bibisco.com](http://www.bibisco.com)) to my Downloads folder and unzipped it. This created a folder named `bibisco` containing all the required files. But `bibisco` won't run.

How can I make `bibisco` work?

Answer (score 1):

**For Ubuntu 18.04 and bibisco 2**

Linux 18.04 LTS missing a library needed by bibisco: libgconf2-4.

So, to run bibisco on Linux 18.04 LTS you have to install this library.
From the terminal:

```
sudo apt -y install libgconf2-4
```

Taken from bibisco's github wiki FAQ [page](https://github.com/andreafeccomandi/bibisco/wiki/bibisco-version-2.X-FAQ:-Frequently-Asked-Question).

Answer (score 0):

From bibisco's GitHub repo (https://github.com/andreafeccomandi/bibisco) :

> bibisco doesn't need to be installed. After download:
>
> 1. unzip downloaded file
> 2. if your operating system is windows launch bibisco.exe; if your operating system is linux launch bibisco
> 3. write your novel

I guess you should have a `bibisco` executable in the uncompressed archive ? Try running it using `./bibisco`.

You might need to change its permissions : `chmod u+x bibisco`

Then : `./bibisco`

Comment: Following Brummbaer's advice I ran chmod then ./bibisco. After a few seconds disk activity the following appeared: Segmentation fault (core dumped). Any further help much appreciated.

Comment: @RobW then the executable is broken or incompatible with your environment. Segfaults have many possible causes :/

Answer (score 0):

Wrote to bibisco. This is the answer they gave me and it worked. I had to install two different library files that Ubuntu is missing to get it to work, but, they told me which ones under a link for if you are having Linux related problems and all is now fine.

bibisco works with Ubuntu and the installation is really simple, take a look at the official instructions, [How to install bibisco](https://bibisco.gitbook.io/docs/how-to-install-bibisco).

The missing dependencies, which you can install with `apt`, are `libgconf-2-4` and `libgtk2.0-0`, as detailed in the ["Linux installation problems"](https://bibisco.gitbook.io/docs/how-to-install-bibisco/linux-installation-problems) section of the instructions.

From the bibisco library, you have to download the file `bibisco-linux-x64-2.2.0-CE.zi`p if you are using the Community Edition or `bibisco-linux-x64-2.2.0-CE.zip` if you are using the Supporters Edition.